# скрипты в cron не запускаются

Tags: linux, debian, cron, crontab

перепробовал кучу вариантов не помогает..

есть два скрипта. Один надо запускать раз в день, второй при запуске системы.

через `crontab -e` из под рута (скрипты требуют рут доступа) задал две команды

```
@reboot bash /bin/bash/ /home/user/script1.sh

0 23 * * * bash /bin/bash/ /home/user/script2.sh
```

Если запускать скрипт из терминала все работает, в них ошибок нет. Пробовал и без `bash /bin/bash` и подключать переменные окружения. Ничего не помогает, скрипты не запускаются. В логах (`grep CRON /var/log/syslog`) пусто, даже не пытается запустить их.

Debian 11

Comment: Попробуйте в самое начало каждого скрипта вставить строку типа *date >> /home/user/my_log.txt* и посмотрите, что происходит. А ещё мне любопытно - на этом компе действительно есть каталог */home/user/* ?

Comment: А зачем у вас слеш в конце /bin/bash ?

Comment: Да и вместо bash должен быть root. В общем man crontab стоит почитать

Comment: слеша в конце в самом файле нет, опечатался. Каталога /home/user/ тоже нет.
заменил на bash на root, добавил вывод даты в лог, при загрузке системы там ничего нет, при ручном запуске скрипта, очевидно дата и время записываются.